# if cell doesn't contain a word then display it in the end of a words range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement

I'd like to display bellow a range of datas specific words if they don't exist in this specific range, based on an array list.

1- For example.Let's say I've got an array list in which fruits name are located;

```
Fruits = Array("apple","cherry","banana","peach","pomegranate","mango")
```

2- And that I have the following column(A) in which each cells are filled by multiple fruits words...

| Fruits |
| --- |
| cherry |
| cherry |
| banana |
| banana |
| banana |
| apple |
| apple |

The objective is to :

- display bellow the range of words (up above) every words from the array list that aren't in this column.

For instance "peach","pomegranate","mango" are not in this list so it the code must return the following value;

| Fruits |
| --- |
| cherry |
| cherry |
| banana |
| banana |
| banana |
| apple |
| apple |
| **peach** |
| **pomegranate** |
| **mango** |

I tried to code it but as soon as I run my code every fruits are getting listed regardless if there are existing in the column or not.

```
Sub Fruties()

Dim LR1 , j, i ,fruits as long
Dim Good As Integer
Fruits = Array("apple","cherry","banana","peach","pomegranate","mango")

Good = 0
Worksheets("Fruit list").Activate

LR1 = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To LR1
   With Range("A" & i)
    For j = LBound(Fruits) To UBound(Fruits)
      If .Value Like "*" & Fruits(j) & "*" Then
       Good = Good + 1
      Else
       Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1).Select
       Range("A20:A" & UBound(Fruits) + 1) _
    = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Fruits)
      
    Exit For   
    End If
     
   Next j
  End With
 Next i
```

I would heavily appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Sub Fruties()

    Dim LR1, j, i, fruits As Long
    Dim FruitExists As Boolean
    Dim arrFruits As Variant
    
    arrFruits = Array("apple", "cherry", "banana", "peach", "pomegranate", "mango")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fruit list")
   
        For j = LBound(arrFruits) To UBound(arrFruits)
                        
            LR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To LR1
            
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = arrFruits(j) Then
                    FruitExists = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    FruitExists = False
                End If
                
            Next i
            
            If FruitExists = False Then
                .Range("A" & LR1 + 1).Value = arrFruits(j)
            End If
     
        Next j
        
    End With
  
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this, which will search each cell for each fruit.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Fruties()
Dim rng As Range
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim fruits As Variant
Dim result As Variant
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idxFruit As Long
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean

    fruits = Array("apple", "cherry", "banana", "peach", "pomegranate", "mango")

    ReDim result(UBound(fruits))
    
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    arrData = rng
    
    For idxFruit = LBound(fruits, 1) To UBound(fruits, 1)
        boolFound = False
        For idxRow = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
            If arrData(idxRow, 1) Like "*" & fruits(idxFruit) & "*" Then
                boolFound = True
            End If
        Next idxRow
        
        If Not boolFound Then
            result(cnt) = fruits(idxFruit)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next idxFruit
    
    ReDim Preserve result(cnt - 1)
    
    rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count).Resize(cnt).Value = Application.Transpose(result)
    
End Sub
```

If there is only going to be a single value in each cell then you could use this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Fruties()
Dim rng As Range
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim fruits As Variant
Dim result As Variant
Dim Res As Variant
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idxFruit As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean

    fruits = Array("apple", "cherry", "banana", "peach", "pomegranate", "mango")

    ReDim result(UBound(fruits))
    
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    arrData = rng
    
    For idxFruit = LBound(fruits, 1) To UBound(fruits, 1)
    
        Res = Application.Match(fruits(idxFruit), arrData, 0)
        If IsError(Res) Then
            result(cnt) = fruits(idxFruit)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next idxFruit
    
    ReDim Preserve result(cnt - 1)
    
    rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count).Resize(cnt).Value = Application.Transpose(result)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: A different way, but it Worked perfectly as well !

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It should be very fast, using arrays (working in memory) and not iterating between the the fruits range:

```
Sub MissingFruits()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrFr, arrMiss, Fruits, mtch, El, k
 
 Set sh = Worksheets("Fruit list")
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arrFr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value  'put the range to be processed in an array
 Fruits = Array("apple", "cherry", "banana", "peach", "pomegranate", "mango")
 
 ReDim arrMiss(UBound(arrFr) - 1) 'Redim the array to make place for the missing fruits
 For Each El In Fruits            'iterate between Fruits array elements:
    mtch = Application.match(El, arrFr, 0) 'find a match for existing fruits
    If IsError(mtch) Then         'if not a match:
       arrMiss(k) = El: k = k + 1 'put the missing one in missing array
    End If
 Next
 ReDim Preserve arrMiss(k - 1)    'keep only not empty elements
 
 'drop the processing array result, at once:
 sh.cells(lastR + 2, "A").Resize(UBound(arrMiss) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrMiss)
End Sub
```